# Load all tabs into DOM on app startup (using Ionic)

Tags: javascript, view, tabs, ionic-framework

I have an app with a tabbed interface, which consists of three tabs. When the user takes certain actions on tab1, it dynamically creates elements that should appear on the second tab. The problem is when I try to dynamically create that content within my javascript, I'm getting cannot set attribute of "null", which I'm assuming is because the second tab isn't loaded into the dom yet. If I first navigate to the second tab, then back to the first tab, it works fine. I'm not really using angular the way it's normally probably used. Everything is done in javascript. I just have a barebones app.js for the underlying UI.

Essentially, I just want to have all three tabs loaded into the DOM on app startup so I can dynamically modify the contents of any tab from any other tab. Not sure how to do this. Here's what my app.js looks like:

var myApp = angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ngCordova'])

```
myApp.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }

    $cordovaStatusbar.overlaysWebView(true)
    $cordovaStatusbar.styleHex('#4a87ee')
    $ionicConfigProvider.views.forwardCache(true);
  });
});

myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('tabs', {
      url: "/tab",
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
    })

    .state('tabs.home', {
      url: "/home",
      views: {
        'home-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/home.html"
        }
      }
    })

    .state('tabs.favorites', {
      url: "/favorites",
      views: {
        'favorites-tab': {
          template: "templates/favorites.html",
          controller: 'AppCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

    .state('tabs.settings', {
      url: "/settings",
      views: {
        'settings-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/settings.html"
        }
      }
    });


   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/tab/home");

})

myApp.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {

})
```

And my basic app structure/html looks like this:

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive"></ion-nav-bar>

<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>

<script id="templates/tabs.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-tabs class="tabs-positive tabs-icon-only">

    <ion-tab title="Videos" icon-on="ion-ios-home" icon-off="ion-ios-home-outline" href="#/tab/home">
      <ion-nav-view name="home-tab"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

    <ion-tab title="Favorites" icon-on="ion-ios-star" icon-off="ion-ios-star-outline" href="#/tab/favorites">

      <ion-nav-view name="favorites-tab"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

    <ion-tab title="Settings" icon-on="ion-ios-gear" icon-off="ion-ios-gear-outline" href="#/tab/settings">
      <ion-nav-view name="settings-tab"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

  </ion-tabs>
</script>

<!-- **************************** HOME TAB **************************** -->
<script id="templates/home.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view view-title="Lmao!Tube">

        <ion-content has-bouncing="true" overflow-scroll="true" class="iframe-wrapper">

            <div id="videoList"> </div>

        </ion-content>

    </ion-view>
</script>

<!-- **************************** FAVORITES TAB **************************** -->  
<script id="templates/favorites.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view view-title="Favorites" >

        <ion-content has-bouncing="true" overflow-scroll="true" class="iframe-wrapper">

            <div id="favoriteList"></div>

        </ion-content>

    </ion-view>

 </script>

<!-- **************************** SETTINGS TAB **************************** -->
<script id="templates/settings.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view view-title="Settings">

        <ion-content>

        </ion-content>

    </ion-view>
</script>
```

Comment: Yeah I don't think that's how it's usually used.  Changes in the structure of each tab content should probably be saved as data in services and then accessed via your controller to dynamically display the content depending on what they did previously.  For instance, they click on home, the home controller saves data to "GlobalService", you pass GlobalService in your favorites controller and based on that value in GlobalService you change the content of that tab.  Does that make sense?  Once I get a better idea of what you are doing, I'll give an answer.

Comment: meh, not really. I'm not really very familiar with Ionic at all. All my app logic is javascript. I'm just using Ionic because it was the only framework I could find with all the UI components I wanted without having to jump through hoops and go around my a$$ to get to my elbow.

Comment: Oops... essentially I have youtube videos loading on the home screen. There is an option/button to add the video to favorites. When the user clicks add to favorites, it goes into a favorites array and should load the video in the favorites tab. By logic works fine except for the fact that I have to navigate to the second tab first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually after rereading your question, you want to do it a different way.  Once you click on the tab, it is placed on the stack and the content is rendered, that's why it only works when you push back and forward.  What would be a better way is utilizing AngularJS and the application framework by saving changes like boolean values in a Service.  A service is an object instantiated only once to hold information and pass it around from controller to controller.  You can use the service to hold values that the controller dynamically creates content from, and in your templates you can use AngularJS's directives like `ng-show` and `ng-if` etc...

For instance in services.js you could have:

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])
    .service('MyService', function() {
        var Stuff = {};
        this.set = function(key, value) {
            Stuff[key] = value;
        };
        this.get = function(key) {
            return Stuff[key];
        }
    });
```

And in your home controller

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', function(MyService, $scope) {
    MyService.set('home', true);
})
```

And in your favorites controller

```
.controller('FavCtrl', function(MyService, $scope) {
    if (MyService.get('home') === true) {
        // set a variable or return list or query or whatever you want
        // lets say it's an array
        $scope.list = [1,2,3];
    } else {
        $scope.list = [4,5,6];
    }
})
```

And in your template you could do something like:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in list">
    {{i}}
</div>
```

And that should print out 1 2 3 if they clicked home tab, and 4 5 6 if not.

If you're new to angular go here: http://campus.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js/intro?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=course&gclid=CjwKEAjw9bKpBRD-geiF8OHz4EcSJACO4O7TsJ3Mx9m9DOH47-6rmFshzUkkkHzJFhJcNiPl1it9JRoCN_fw_wcB

Pretty nifty course that gets you knowing some things about AngularJS pretty fast to work with Ionic.  Ionic is a great framework.

Comment: Looks pretty nifty, but I have no clue what any of that means... Like I was saying, my app is written in javascript, not angular. I'm using Ionic purely for the UI components. And I'm not looking to rewrite my entire application. If it's this complicated to do something so basic as DOM manipulation, I'll just ditch Ionic and go to an easier to use framework. It's very simple in every other framework I've tried, except for Ionic for some reason; I'm assuming because it's so tightly integrated with Angular.

Comment: Yes it is very tightly integrated with angular, and angularjs is javascript but I think I get what you mean.  You're using this for some side project apart of a larger application.  If you don't know much about angular or ionic (which apparently you don't if you don't have a clue what I just said) then either A) you're better off learning more about it or B) skipping it all together.  Ionic is written on top of Angular as it's foundation framework, working with ionic would call for at least a basic working understanding of Angular.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I think it does answer the question and goes above and beyond.